# unable to display data from local storage to mat-table.using angular material table

Tags: angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular8, mat-table

[console image attached
[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFV0J.png)//hi,I am unable to display local-storage data in mat-table which I stored in formvalue as formValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form-data')); at submit click function.

--------------------------htmlfile code------------------------------------------------------

```
<pre>

<div id="homewid" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 main-head text-right">
      <!-- <h1 class="main-head text-center"><i class="material-icons">
            dashboard
          </i>Dashboard</h1> -->
      <!-- mat-raised-button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Add Employee</button>
      <!-- <button matTooltip="create new record"   type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Add Employee</button> -->
    </div>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Enter emp_id, name, project... ">
    </mat-form-field>

    <div class="mat-elevation-z8 table">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="formValue" matSort>

        <!-- ID Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Emp_Id </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Progress Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.email}} </td>
        </ng-container>



        <!-- Color Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="contact">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Contact </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.contact}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="project">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Project </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.project}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="project">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Edit/Delete </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.project}} </td>
            </ng-container> -->

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        </tr>
      </table>

      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<!-- 
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document"> -->
<!-- <br><br> -->
<pre class="card card-block card-header">{{message}}</pre>
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="confirm()">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Create Employee Record</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" (click)="modalRef.hide()" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


          <!-- 
          <div class="example-container"> -->
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="emp_id" type="text" matInput placeholder="Emp_Id">
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="name" type="text" matInput placeholder="Name">
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="email" type="text" matInput placeholder="Email">
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="contact" type="text" matInput placeholder="Contact">
          </mat-form-field>



          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="project" type="text" matInput placeholder="Project">
          </mat-form-field>
          <!-- </div> -->

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="footerbtn" (click)="confirm()">SUBMIT</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="confirm()" >Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="decline()" >No</button> -->
  </div>
</ng-template>


</pre>
```

===================================================================================================

========================ts file code==============================================

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
// import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';


var formValue : any = {};
export interface UserData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  contact: string;
  project: string;
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  // providers: [Location]
})



export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  registrationForm: FormGroup;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'contact', 'project'];

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  message: string;



  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private modalService: BsModalService) {

    const users = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, k) => createNewUser(k + 1));



    // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);
  }


  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, { class: 'modal-sm' });
  }




  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    this.registrationForm = new FormGroup({
      emp_id: new FormControl(),
      name: new FormControl(),
      email: new FormControl(),
      contact: new FormControl(),
      project: new FormControl()

    });
  }


  confirm(): void {
    console.log(this.registrationForm.value);


    localStorage.setItem('form-data', JSON.stringify(this.registrationForm.value));

     formValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form-data'));

    console.log(formValue);


    //  formValuee =  Object.assign({}, formValue);
    // console.log(formValuee);
    this.message = 'Confirmed!';
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }


  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

}


/** Builds and returns a new User. */
function createNewUser(id:number) : UserData {



  return {  
    id: formValue.id,
    name: formValue.name,
    email: formValue.email,
    contact: formValue.contact,
    project: formValue.project 

  };
}
```

============================================module file code=======================================

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SideBarComponent } from './projectManager/side-bar/side-bar.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './projectManager/navigation/navigation.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './projectManager/registration/registration.component';
import { NgxEditorModule } from 'ngx-editor';
import { MatAutocompleteModule, MatSnackBarModule, MatChipsModule, MatBadgeModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTooltipModule, MatExpansionModule, MatSelectModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatIconModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatButtonModule, MatInputModule, MatCardModule, MatProgressBarModule, MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { EditComponent } from './projectManager/edit/edit.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './projectManager/home/home.component';
import { AvatarModule } from 'ngx-avatar';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

//import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SideBarComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
    EditComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    AvatarModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    NgxEditorModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([


      { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
      { path: 'navigation', component: NavigationComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'edit', component: EditComponent },
      { path: 'sidebar', component: SideBarComponent },
//     { path: '', redirectTo: 'registration', pathMatch: 'full' },

    ])

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

========================================css file code=================================================

```
:root {  font-size: 10px; } 

/* .modal {
  margin-bottom:50em;
 } */
 /* .center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} */


/* .modal-backdrop {
  display:none;
} */

#homewid{
margin-left: 12em;

}

.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}


.main-head{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 12%;
    padding: 25px;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .main-head{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 18%;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 276px){
  .main-head{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 48%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 226px){
  .main-head{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 68%;
}
}

.example-form {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .example-full-width {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
     color: white;  
    padding: 10px;

  }

  table {
    width: 100%;

  }

  .title{
    width: 30%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.gridbtn{
    width: 30%;
}

.title-expansion{
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black !important;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.status-done{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(238, 234, 30) !important;
}

.status-progress{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(44, 150, 18) !important;
}

.status-backlog{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red !important;
}

.status-testing{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: darkorchid;
}

.slideout{
  animation: yourAnimation 0.5s forwards 0s ease;
}

#exampleModalCenter { 
  display:true;
 }


@keyframes yourAnimation{
  0%{
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
  100%{
      transform: translateX(0%);
      }
}



table {
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-form-field {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console when running this? Does it compile? If you could be clearer on what the issue is, would help the community provide an answer.

Comment: sir, I am attaching screenshot of console ,it shows no errors.actually I want to print the object data which I can see in console also  with no errors. That is the same data which is coming from the form on submit click.

Comment: sir,I have attached the console image link in original asked question.please do let me know if other information required. and thanks very much  for your immediate support.